# What's preventing the white font color to work?

Tags: html, css

Would someone care to help me out or point me into the right direction? For some strange reason, the front color in my php file keeps being returned in black while it is set to white.

I've tried to put "color: white;" as well as "color: #FFFFFF;" to make it work, in every part of the css, but so far no luck.

Image reference:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXQKd.jpg (I've hovered over the black part with my cursor to show you it gets absorbed into the background entirely otherwise)

Php file:

```
<div class="newsblock">
              <?php
                /*------------------------------------------------------*/
                /*--------------------CONFIG TIMEZONE-------------------*/
                /*------------------------------------------------------*/
                    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_EN', 'pt_EN.utf-8', 'pt_EN.utf-8', 'english');
                    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
                /*------------------------------------------------------*/
                /*------------------------------------------------------*/
                    require_once("status/inc/rsslib.php");
                    echo RSS_Display ( $ticim['RSSall'], 4 );
                    echo NO_EDIT ( $ticim['RSS_SIG']);
              ?>
</div>
```

css file:

```
body { color: white; !important; padding: 0; margin: 0; background: #FFF; border: 0; outline: 0; overflow: hidden; font-family: "Arial", sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; }
.newsblock table { color: white; !important; width: 110%; font-size: 10px; border-collapse: collapse; white-space: nowrap; }
.newsblock table tr td { color: white; !important; font-weight: bold; padding: 1px 0; }
.newsblock table tr td a { color: white; !important; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1; font-size: 10px; display: block; }
.newsblock table tr.row_1 td { color: white; !important; font-weight: bold; }
.newsblock table tr.row_6 td { color: white; !important; background: none; color: }
.newsblock table tr td.date { color: white; !important; font-weight: bold; }
```

It'd be great if the date could be returned into white/visible, like the text in the other column.

Comment: First, make a quick fix: remove the semicolon between `white` and `!important`, otherwise the `!important` isn't being applied to your `color` property. That is, change `color: white; !important;` to `color: white !important;`.

Comment: Thank you. I went ahead and tried this, no difference unfortunately.

Comment: The PHP isn't relevant. Show us the HTML you are trying to apply the CSS to. Preferably using the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: Whether or not it made a difference, it's important to fix incorrect code so that you can rule out possibilities. It's an important part of the problem solving process. With that being said, we can't really help you any further with the code you've shown here. We need to see your generated HTML, any additional CSS rules that may be overriding the ones shown here, etc. I would encourage you to check your web console for any content security policy errors and use the inspector tool to see which CSS rule is taking precedence for the black font color.